# Hot corner stopped working?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, gnome, touchpad, macbook

I have a 2010 white Macbook with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed and the hot corner seems to have stopped working in the vanilla GNOME session.

Flicking the various options in GNOME Tweaks, installing a custom hot corner extension or using dconf Editor don't seem to have an effect.

The only things that I can think of that I've done differently since the initial installation of the vanilla GNOME Session is that I installed the NVIDIA proprietary drivers and the `xorg-xinput-mtrack` drivers.

Does anyone know of any possible solutions to get the top left hot corner working again?

Comment: Does it work with a regular mouse?

Comment: @gabmus yeah it works. Seems to be the mtrack driver that's causing the issue. In fact, it seems like any hidden docks on the edge of the screen don't work either. Not just the hot corner in gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be your touchpad driver. Some input drivers (usually in virtual machines) try to simulate a pen graphic tablet.

This means that some UI elements that rely on overshooting beyond the limits of the screen won't work.

If you think about it, you can't overshoot a movement in a graphic tablet, the tracked surface just ends and no further input is sent. Try switching to another touchpad driver, like for instance `libinput`.